# Websphere Application Level Environment Variables

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

Is it possible to set **environment variables** at the **application level** in websphere?

Websphere servers can host multiple applications. Any environment variable applied at the server level applies to **all** the applications on that server. Is it possible to create variables that only apply to individual applications?

For example:
Lets say we have a **SpreadsheetApp** and a **DocsApp** running on the same server. They both share some common code that can be configured via an environment variable called **DocStorageLocation**. Is it possible to set the **DocStorageLocation** differently for both applications?

Alternatively, is there another way of configuring **multiple applications** running on the **same server**?

Answer (score 7):

**QUESTION 1**

> Is it possible to set the DocStorageLocation differently for both
>   applications?

I don't think it is possible. Websphere's environment variables are meant to be used by the server itself. A variable has only three possible scopes, which are Server, Cluster and Node.

For instance, an **ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH** environment variable on *server1, node1* scope could be used for the JDBC provider on *node1* (classPath = ${ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/ojdbc14.jar).

The question is : "why can't I set a different value for my application only" ? But my guess is that as long as the server, clusters and nodes are started, it does not make sense to override this value for a deployed application.

Although I think it is not possible, I still tried. But I did not manage to override an environment variable set for the websphere server.

**QUESTION 2**

> Alternatively, is there another way of configuring multiple
>   applications running on the same server?

***Environment entry***

You could add an environment entry to your web.xml deployment descriptor, a variable you can look up for.

```xml
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>DocStorageLocation</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>C:/DocStorage</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

Then test, look up for this variable in the java class :

```java
//TEST
Object l_test = null;
try {
    Context l_ctx = new InitialContext();
    l_test = l_ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/DocStorageLocation");
} catch (NamingException e1) {
    // TODO
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

***URL ressource for .properties file***

You can create an URL ressource. It would link to a .properties file set on a local host or any server, so each property could be set to a different value depending on the environment.

For instance, JNDI name **url/environmentJndiName** with value *file:///server1/environment.properties* on server1, and file:///server2/environment.properties on server2.

Then on server 1, you could set *docStorageLocation=value1* in the environment.properties file, *docStorageLocation=value2* on server2.

In your deployment descriptor web.xml, the ressource's reference would be the same. You wouldn't have to change this reference in the java source :

```xml
   <resource-ref>
         <res-ref-name>url/environment</res-ref-name>
         <res-type>java.net.URL</res-type>
         <res-auth>Application</res-auth>
         <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
   </resource-ref>
```

Then use this ressource to read the properties.

```java
try {
    Context l_ctx = new InitialContext();
    URL l_url = (URL) l_ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/url/environment");
    // New properties
    Properties l_properties = new Properties();
    // Load properties
    this.loadProps(l_properties, l_url.getPath());

} catch (NamingException e1) {
    // TODO
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Bloc catch auto-généré
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    ...

private void loadProps(final Properties p_properties, final String p_fileLocation)
    throws IOException
{
    // Open stream
    BufferedInputStream l_is = new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(
                    new File(p_fileLocation)));

    p_properties.load(l_is);
    // Close stream
    l_is.close();
}
```

You will need to bind the ressource reference **url/environment** of the web.xml to the JNDI name **url/environmentJndiName** set for this ressource on the websphere server. Modify the ibm-web-bnd.xml file with websphere, the sun-web.xml file with glassfish, etc.

**THANKS**

If there is a better solution, or if it does not answer the question, let me know. I am still learning but I have been working with websphere for a while - even if I prefer other solutions. Thanks, @+.

Comment: Thanks Magleff. I was hoping there was some way of keeping this configuration outside of the EAR/WAR. We have many different test environments and I was hoping we could deploy an identical EAR to all of them, completely separating 'application code' from 'environment configuration'. Do you think there is a way to put a properties file on the 'Application classpath' without it being part of the EAR?

Comment: @KevSheedy I think you could use an URL ressource. I edited my answer.